# Classic ASP converting ampersand values into characters

Tags: html, sql, asp-classic

I am saving html values to the DB.

Values such as:

```
&reg; &#174;
```

They save correctly to DB, but when I pull back the code it returns to the textarea as:

® ®

What can I do to conserve this html so that when I resave it it is the html i intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `Server.HTMLEncode` function. This will change all special characters to their & code.

So,

`Server.HTMLEncode("A Tale of Two Cities ©")` will return `A Tale of Two Cities &#169;`

[Link](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_htmlencode.asp)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ASP issue, it is an HTML issue if you write an HTML entity to a textarea as

```
&reg; or &#174;
```

the browser will convert it, you need to write it as

```
&amp;reg;
```

so that it displays as &reg;

In ASP:

```
str="&reg; &#174;"
str=replace(str,"&","&amp;")
```

Comment: Thanks. I have to keep it simple as I won't be the one inputting the HTML. I will have little control over what the users type.

Comment: Yes you do :)

You can format whatever the users enter into. You can either do it client side with javascript (real time or on submit) or process the text server side.

Comment: yes, but it will confuse them to see these changes when they review it and it will affect how it renders in my preview window as it will just look like "&reg;" instead of ®. I appreciate your answer but  Server.HTMLEncode just fits better for this situation.